# How to share a filtered object array between parent and child's

Tags: arrays, angular, filter, parent

I'm filtering an object array of locations based on criteria selected, now I'd like to pass that filtered array to a child and sibling components and I'm unsure what is the best way to do it.

I have created a little mockup on Stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dgxjyj

As you can see, the filter pipe works great within the Filter Component (parent) - I just don't know how to update the other child and sibling components with the same results. Maybe I'm overcomplicating it.

I have tried to store the filtered array and then pass it by using the @Output decorator.

Answer (score 1):

I went through your Stackblitz code. That Having the below structure

```
<my-app> //parent

   <app-filter></app-filter> //Child to my-app and sibling to other two

   <app-my-locations></app-my-locations> //child to my-app and sibling to other two

   <app-my-map></app-my-map> //child to my app and sibling to other two

</my-app>
```

Anyway in your example, In the `filter component` you have to emit the filtered location to the parent(`<my-app>`). [Refer to this angular document](https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs#sending-data-to-a-parent-component)

Then you have to send the data to the other two components(my-location, my-map) by the input decorator. [refer to this documentation](https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs#sending-data-to-a-child-component)